# iterate through elements in array within active record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do a comparison and return a statement whether the item is inside of the array or not. Menu is an object that I have in active record which is composed of 3 attributes, the menu type, meal and the restaurant id. For the meal attribute I had a variable set to it which is actually an array that contains the names of meals.

In my code when I do puts"#{menu.meal}" I get back...

```
["Pancakes W/ Eggs and Bacon", "Bacon Egg and Cheese", "Oatmeal W/ Raisins", "Scrambled Eggs W/ Grits", "Blueberry Waffles W/ Syrup", "Chocolate Chip Pancakes W/ Sausage", "Yogurt Muffin"]
```

which is the array of meals that I have set in my seeds file.
In the code below what I am trying to do is when the user enters the meal that it wants I want to search through all the meals if it exits, and if it does then the user can proceed and if not I want to output an error message saying that it does not exist.

```
 puts "What meal would you like to order"
 item_meal = gets.chomp


 menus_meals = res.menus.select do |menu|
   binding.pry
   menu.meal == item_meal
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". When asking about code we need the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem. As is your code won't run so we can't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code is correct, I would just advise that you use `include?` in this case as you are only trying to check if `item_meal` is present in `menus`.

```
if res.menus.include?(item_meal)
  # user proceeds
else
  # show an error message
end
```

Comment: Depending on length of array and where the item you're searching for may be, `.find` can be orders of magnitude faster than `.include?`.   See [this gist as an example](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/516188e62eba3e0e3c82a7e9ac928398).